# The approach to calculating 'similar' objects based on certain weighted criteria

Tags: math, machine-learning, data-mining, taxonomy

I have a site that has multiple Project objects. Each project has (for example):

- multiple tags
- multiple categories
- a size
- multiple types
- etc.

I would like to write a method to grab all 'similar' projects based on the above criteria. I can easily retrieve similar projects for each of the above singularly (i.e. projects of a similar size or projects that share a category etc.) but I would like it to be more intelligent then just choosing projects that either have all the above in common, or projects that have at least one of the above in common.

Ideally, I would like to weight each of the criteria, i.e. a project that has a tag in common is less 'similar' then a project that is close in size etc. A project that has two tags in common is more similar than a project that has one tag in common etc.

What approach (practically and mathimatically) can I take to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The common way to handle this (in machine learning at least) is to create a metric which measures the similarity -- A [Jaccard metric](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jaccard_index) seems like a good match here, given that you have types, categories, tags, etc, which are not really numbers.

Once you have a metric, you can speed up searching for similar items by using a KD tree, vp-tree or another metric tree structure, provided your metric obeys the triangle inequality( d(a,b) < d(a,c) + d(c, b) )

Comment: @)oel: Where did you get the geometry?

Comment: @David: Not sure what you mean here?  The geometry comes inherently as a byproduct of the metric.

Comment: I suppose if you would use the Jaccard metric then you would actually get a metric for each property you want to consider. At this point you would have two choices, either combining all metrics into one, so that you can solve the problem on just that combined metric, at which point you would have to decide weights for each metric (which might be a problem in itself), or you could compute the Pareto set (or Pareto frontier) and choose among that reduced set.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is, that there are obviously an infinite number of ways of solving this.

First of all, define a similarity measure for each of your attributes (tag similarity, category similarity, description similarity, ...)

Then try to normalize all these similarities to use a common scale, e.g. 0 to 1, with 0 being most similar, and the values having a similar distribution.

Next, assign each feature a weight. E.g. tag similarity is more important than description similarity.

Finally, compute a combined similarity as weighted sum of the individual similarities.

There is an infinite number of ways, as you can obviously assign arbitrary weights, have various choices for the single-attribute similarities already, infinite number of ways of normalizing the individual values. And so on.

There are methods for learning the weights. See *ensemble methods*. However, to learn the weights you need to have user input on what is a good result and what not. Do you have such *training data*?

Answer (score 0):

1. Start with a value of 100 in each category.
2. Apply penalties. Like, -1 for each kB difference in size, or -2 for each tag not found in the other project. You end up with a value of 0..100 in each category.
3. Multiply each category's value with the "weight" of the category (i.e., similarity in size is multiplied with 1, similarity in tags with 3, similarity in types with 2).
4. Add up the weighted values.
5. Divide by the sum of weight factors (in my example, 1 + 3 + 2 = 6) to get an overall similarity of 0..100.

Possibilities to reduce the comparing of projects below the initial O(n^2) (i.e. comparing each project with each other) is heavily depending on context. It might be the real crux of your software, or it might not be necessary at all if `n` is low.